# How to replace variables in terraform

Tags: terraform

I tried creating a user defined variable and tried to call it under resource configuration tab.

```
locals {

    rname = "${var.build == "production" ? "PROD_RHEL7_x64"}"

        }

resource_configuration = {

       "${local.rname.ip_address}" = ""
       "${local.rname.name}"       = ""

                          }
```

The expected output should replace the local.rname.ipaddress to PROD_RHEL7_x64.ip_address

The actual output is

> Error: Error parsing /work/test.tf: object expected closing RBRACE got: EOF

Comment: Looks like a syntax error, seems to miss the second half (FALSEVAR) of the tenary operator in locals. `CONDITION ? TRUEVAL : FALSEVAL`

Comment: added FALSEVAL locals {

    rname = "${var.build == "production" ? "PROD_RHEL7_x64" : "test" }"

        } . But got error Error: Error parsing /work/vra.tf: object expected closing RBRACE got: EOF

Comment: Are you sure that you have a corresponding amount of opening & closing brackets? The error indicates that something is wrong with braces. The above quoted section looks ok. Eventually in another part, not shown here, or a completely different project file?

Comment: Try using a decent editor/ide supporting hcl in order to spot such errors easier. I personally like IntelliJ with the HCL plugin.

Comment: @hargut seems like i missed to close one brace. Now i am getting another error. Can't use dot (.) attribute access in local.rname.hon.application; use square bracket indexing in: